# Bitwise operation for unsigned long long int is not applied when it's over 32bits

Tags: c, macos, assembly, x86, bit-manipulation

I'm just some test on Mac OS X. But I don't understand why this happens.

when I try to apply some bitwise operation on unsigned long long int,
when some operation is over 32bit, there's no appliance about the operation.

the code is below..

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>


#define KEY_MAX             31
#define INDEX_MASK          0b11111


unsigned long long int makePlain(unsigned long long int chipherText, int pattern);


static char testArray[] = {
    'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E',
    'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J',
    'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O',
    'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T',
    'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y',
    'Z', ' ', '@', '@', '@' };


int main(void) {
    unsigned int i;
    unsigned long long int chipherText = 0b1010100100101010101111001000110101110101001001100111010;
    unsigned long long int plain = 0;

    for (i = 2; i <  3; i++) {
        plain = makePlain(chipherText, i);
        int j;
        for (j = 0; j < 11; j++) {
            printf("IDX=[%d] : %d\n", j,(unsigned int)(plain >> (5 * j) & INDEX_MASK));
        }

        printf("%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c\n",
                testArray[(unsigned int)((plain >> (5 * 10)) & INDEX_MASK)],
                testArray[(unsigned int)((plain >> (5 * 9)) & INDEX_MASK)],
                testArray[(unsigned int)((plain >> (5 * 8)) & INDEX_MASK)],
                testArray[(unsigned int)((plain >> (5 * 7)) & INDEX_MASK)],
                testArray[(unsigned int)((plain >> (5 * 6)) & INDEX_MASK)],
                testArray[(unsigned int)((plain >> (5 * 5)) & INDEX_MASK)],
                testArray[(unsigned int)((plain >> (5 * 4)) & INDEX_MASK)],
                testArray[(unsigned int)((plain >> (5 * 3)) & INDEX_MASK)],
                testArray[(unsigned int)((plain >> (5 * 2)) & INDEX_MASK)],
                testArray[(unsigned int)((plain >> (5 * 1)) & INDEX_MASK)],
                testArray[(unsigned int)((plain >> (5 * 0)) & INDEX_MASK)] );
    }

    return 0; }


unsigned long long int makePlain(unsigned long long int chipherText, int pattern) {
    int i;
    unsigned int temp;
    unsigned long long int plain = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
        temp = ((chipherText >> (5 * i)) & INDEX_MASK);
        temp = temp ^ pattern;
        printf("[%d]:temp -after xor : %d\n", i, temp);
        plain |= (temp << (5 * i)); // Here is make problems.
    }

    return plain; }
```

(at first, the code isn't good to see.. sorry everyone.)

Please see the last line of loops on makePlain function..

when variable i is 6, it's write bits over 32 bits.
after that, all operation of "plain |=" isn't apply but remain as 0 about bits over 32bits.

below is Xcode Debbugger result.

[image]

So, I just confirm the asm and i found that kind of code..

```
      call    printf
  LM42:
      movl    -4(%rbp), %edx          # i -> edx
      movl    %edx, %eax              # eax = i
      sall    $2, %eax                # i * 4
      addl    %edx, %eax              # i * 5
      movl    -20(%rbp), %edx         # temp -> edx (maybe problem
                                      # becase it load 64bit on 32)
      movl    %eax, %ecx              # eax -> ecx ==> ecx = i * 5
      sall    %cl, %edx               # edx << i * 5 //why 32 bit? 
      movl    %edx, %eax              # eax saving (plain) //why 32bit
      movl    %eax, %eax              # 
      orq>%rax, -16(%rbp)             # saving
```

I think above code is

> plain |= (temp << (5 * i));

on makePlain function.

My question is..

- Why this happen? (I think it's complied as 32 bit register when they're shifted. and they load... when i see asm code..)
- if my thiking is correct.. what kind of complie option solve that happen?
- How can I see the assemble code on Xcode debugger?

Comment: You declared `temp` as `unsigned int`. Try with `unsigned long`.

Comment: Don't post images of text!

Comment: @Jester: Neither has a specific bit-width.

Comment: For fixed bitwidth operations use fixed bitwidth types! See `stdint.h`/`inttypes.h`. And use the required width **consistently**.

Comment: Try `plain |= ((unsigned long long)temp << (5LL * (unsigned long long)i));`

Comment: @Frankie_C the type to the right of the `<<` operator doesn't matter for this purpose.

Comment: Please make a [mcve], there is a lot of code.

Comment: @FUZxxl I see now that `i` will never be greater than 11. You're right it will never cross 32 bits.

Comment: voted to close as off-topic: typo / brain fart, because the OP just forgot to change the type of `temp` when converting the function to `long long`.

Comment: Thank you very much all! I found the problem by your help! temp should be unsigned long long. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `temp` variable only has 32 bits as it is an `unsigned int`. Change its type to `unsigned long long` to solve your problem.

### What happens?

In this line:

```
plain |= (temp << (5 * i));
```

The variable `temp` has `unsigned int` type which is typically a 32 bit type. The left shift is therefore also a 32 bit shift and whatever is shifted beyond 32 bits is discarded. The code also exhibits undefined behaviour when `i` is greater than 6 as shifting a value by more bits than its type has is undefined.

There are two ways to solve this. One is to give `temp` the right type, the other is to use an appropriate cast to make sure that the shift is an `unsigned long long` shift:

```
plain |= ((unsigned long long)temp << (5 * i));
```

Comment: 3rd alternative: use `1ULL*temp << (5 * i));` as this insures the value shifted is _at least_ as wide as an `unsigned long long`.  Casting could  conceivable narrow an operation.

Comment: @chux Better use `0ULL+temp` so non-optimizing compilers insert a cheap add instead of an expensive multiplication, but otherwise, yes, that's possible. But narrowing doesn't matter as `plain` has type `unsigned long long` anyway.

Comment: My concern about narrow was the narrowing of `temp`, not `plain` and what `plain` could be in the future.  The comment was for general code:  `(some_type)` vs. `*Some_Type_Of_1`.  This first may narrow, the second will never narrow.  Interesting thought about `+0` vs `*1`.  I like `*1` as it has higher precedence yet will keep in mind your idea.

Comment: @chux I perfectly understood your intent. What I wanted to point out is that it doesn't matter if `plain` is narrowed as it is going to be narrowed after the shift anyway.

Comment: True, based on the type of `plain` today.  I am thinking of code maintenance and how to minimized changes to a line-of-code as the types of variables like `temp` and `plain` evolve.  Would be useful if C adopted some extension which allow `plain |= ((typeof(plain)) temp << (5 * i));`.  IAC, using the [same type](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36061245/2410359) for  `plain` and `temp` is simplest.

Answer (score 1):

When you are writing your code always make sure that all the variables depend on each other should be in same datatype. It avoids memory overflow in such cases